# how to get my for loop to compute the distance between coordinates in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im writing a program to calculate distances for each element of a list between latitude and longitude from a file, for instance if my points list has five points p1,p2,p3,p4,
and p5, I want the program to find the distance between points p1 and
p2, p1 and p3, p1 and p4, and p1 and p5. Then compute the distance
between p2 and p3, p2 and p4, p2 and p5 and so on.but cant get the output to calculate the distance between all points in my list.

input from file is 
62.24186067241206,110.85699280829596
32.59293412296685,170.1144522172567
57.96358548631895,65.88075339171547
24.001352068102108,1.3473208526774272
-64.06840683422311,153.52144681056024

```
infile=open('test_part2.txt','r')
lines=infile.readlines()
infile.close()
def get_distance(p1,p2):
        x1=p1[0]
        y1=p1[1]
        x2=p2[0]
        y2=p2[1]
        d=(x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2
        d=d**0.5
        return d
print ('Pairwise distance between points:')
points=[]
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    tokens=line.split(",")
    lat=float(tokens[0].strip())
    lon=float(tokens[1].strip())
    point=[]
    point.append(lat)
    point.append(lon)
    points.append(point)
    for i in range(0,len(points)):
        d=get_distance(point,points[i])
        print(d)
```

expected output is 
66.26088847230339
45.17926239576636
115.99441689212239
133.32118853696534
107.27690301949622
168.9856796040263
98.07518883014596
72.92459951226348
150.24213221549
175.82163417554528

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input file.

Comment: Are all your points in one single line with some are comma-separated and some with space?

Comment: no in the file they are 62.24186067241206,110.85699280829596\n stack overflow keeps posting them like that

Comment: I am asking about the input data format.

Comment: single line no space one comma. Format is (latitude,longitude)

Answer (score 0):

The itertools module provides a combinations function which looks ideal for this, assuming your data is a list of tuple pairs, for example:

```
import itertools as it
#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    points =[(0,0), (4,0), (4,3), (1,1)]
    temp = list(it.combinations(points, 2))
    for pair in temp:
        print(f"{pair} distance = {get_distance(pair[0], pair[1])}")
```

Gives this output:

```
(0, 0), (4, 0) = 4.0
(0, 0), (4, 3) = 5.0
(0, 0), (1, 1) = 1.4142135623730951
(4, 0), (4, 3) = 3.0
(4, 0), (1, 1) = 3.1622776601683795
(4, 3), (1, 1) = 3.605551275463989
```

Edit if you can't use itertools, this might be a workaround:

```
count = 0
combos = []
while count < len(points):
    temp = [(points[count], x) for x in points[count+1:]]
    combos.extend(temp)
    count += 1
for x in combos:
    print x
```

The list comprehension is not too hard to break down into for loops if that's what your school requires. Slicing is more or less a must, however.

Comment: this is for school so im restricted to using for loops

Comment: See above. Hopefully you've seen list comprehensions, but they're just condensed for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to go through the points in two loops. I am assuming we don't have a performance issue here. Also, assuming the points are the way you have described earlier.

> 62.24186067241206,110.85699280829596
>
> 32.59293412296685,170.1144522172567

Updated your code

```
infile = open('test_part2.txt', 'r')
lines = infile.readlines()
infile.close()

def get_distance(p1, p2):
  x1 = p1[0]
  y1 = p1[1]
  x2 = p2[0]
  y2 = p2[1]
  d = (x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2
  d = d ** 0.5
  return d

print('Pairwise distance between points:')
points = []
for line in lines:
  line = line.strip()
  tokens = line.split(",")
  lat = float(tokens[0].strip())
  lon = float(tokens[1].strip())
  point = [lat, lon]
  points.append(point)

for i in range(0, len(points)):
   for j in range(i+1, len(points)):
      d = get_distance(points[j], points[i])
      print(d)
```